# Duplicating workbook and filtering with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save a copy of a workbook and then in the new saved copy of the workbook, filter some items, close it and then repeat the process with the original workbook (for a range of items).

Currently, I am getting an error ("Compile Error: Named argument not found" in here and on top of this I am doubting if my approach is the most efficient method of doing this.

Would love to know what is wrong with this doc and how to improve it?

The macro in question:

```
Sub CECL_Scrub()
'
' CECL_Scrub Macro

'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
 
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range

'In Input sheet, select country list for filter

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set rng = .Sheets("Input").Range("A1:A2")
    End With
    
'Create folders for countries

   Dim i As Integer

        For i = 13 To 14

        ' Checks if folder already exists
            If Len(Dir("C:\Users\me\MacroTestOutput\" & Range("A" & i), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir "C:\Users\me\MacroTestOutput\" & Range("A" & i)
            End If

        Next i

'Define variables and save as new workbook

For Each cl In rng

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Activate
    
' Save separate file in location of choice
    
            Dim Path1 As String
            Dim Path2 As String
            Dim Path3 As String
            Dim myfilename As String
    
            Path1 = "C:\Users\me\MacroTestOutput\"
            Path2 = cl.Value
            Path3 = " - Test"
            
            myfilename = Path1 & Path2 & "\" & Path2 & Path3
            
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=myfilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            
            Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
            Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(myfilename)
    
'Filter of first sheet
        Worksheets("Summary").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$W27").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cl.Value
            
Next cl
    
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

EDIT:

The above code was corrected per the answer to the question

Comment: What line does arise the error?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs` has only 1 parameter, that is filename. It is a copy of the existing wb so you can't change its file type. If you want to do that you need `Workbook.SaveAs`. [SaveCopyAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas), and [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

Comment: @Warcupine I've updated, however I now get a runtime error 1004 and it doesn't seem like the file is being saved?

Comment: You have the wrong slash (forward) in the concatenation of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Why this code did not work was because of incorrect syntax (incorrect slash being used in the file name. This code has been edited and corrected above. Should be valuable to anyone is looking for this in the future